# WPF DataGrid highlight entire row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm using a WPF datagrid to display data. I'm trying to figure out how to highlight the entire row when an item is clicked, including the empty columns/space on the end if there is empty space on the end (I'm using dynamically generated columns). Note, I'm NOT trying to highlight just a particular cell. This https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSLlK.jpg is what I'm seeing. The unused space at the end of the row is space where there is not currently a column, and is not highlighted. I would like for that space to be highlighted as well when the row is clicked. I've tried:

Setting the width to the last column of auto to fill the remaining space. This doesn't work for me because doing this disables the horizontal scroll bar, which I need since I'm using dynamically created columns.

I've also tried adding a style for DataGridRows:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
```

This kind of works, although, when the datagrid loads, or when my program is not in focus, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx4jU.jpg where only the last area of unused space is highlighted.

If possible, I'd prefer not to workaround this by just adding a blank dummy column on the end because this leads to the same problems as just setting the last column width to auto above.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Here is the code for the DataGridRow style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
       x:Key="DataGridRowStyle">

    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="White" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex"
                 Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#efefef" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource RolloverBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the selected brush:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="SelectedBrush"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0"
                  Color="#3399FF" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

The code for the datagrid:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="JobListView"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding UnitStatusCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              Style="{StaticResource JobGridViewStyle}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding JobsListViewSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding JobsListViewSelectedUnitStatusPair}"
              Utility:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding DataGridColumns}"
              ContextMenu="{StaticResource ListViewContextMenu}"
              Margin="10,0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
              AlternationCount="2"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#5A5A5F"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="#5A5A5F">
```

Comment: Can you show the `Style` tag for "DataGridRows"?

Comment: Edited the post to show it

Comment: How are you applying it to the grid? Your code works for me with `RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"` on the DataGrid.

Comment: That is what I'm doing as well. What do you mean when you say works, what behavior are you seeing? I'll edit the question to include the code for the datagrid

Comment: I meant that when I select a row, the whole row turns the desired shade of blue. But here's the funny thing: When I change SelectedBrush to this: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBrush" Color="Red" />` -- I still get the same shade of blue. So that blue must be my system default selection highlight color, and my last comment was utter nonsense. The RolloverBrush is working but my IsSelected trigger does nothing. Let me take another look into this...

Comment: Yes, I set the color to be the default color of the datagrid highlight while I was working on this. After I am able to get this functionality working, I was planning on changing the highlight color

Comment: This is interesting: `<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />` works in the IsSelected trigger.

Comment: But what I *am* seeing is every cell in the row is highlighted -- and I can change the highlight color by defining a resource `<SolidColorBrush Color="#ff9933" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />`

Comment: How are you generating your columns?

Comment: I have a factory class which is reading a settings file and generating the columns the user has selected. I'm generating DataGridTextColumns in and adding them to an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel which is bound to the displayed columns in the DataGrid. This line in the datagrid: Utility:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding DataGridColumns}"            I'm not setting much on the properties of the columns. Just simple things like IsReadOnly/MinWidth/Headers

Comment: Is that where you're creating the "fill" column?

Comment: I'm not currently using a fill column. The "column" on the end of the grid is just unused space that isn't being currently filled by dynamic columns.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe that area's just not part of the row. Can you get to one of the rows' ActualWidth in the debugger?

Comment: I'm using MVVM so I'm not sure how I would get the row's width. I have thought about approaching the problem that way. Check to see if my current columns width are > than the grid width, if not make a dummy fill column, if not then don't have a dummy column. However I don't have a way, as far as I can tell to get to the dataGrid width

Comment: Have you set width for every DataGridColumn.. **Why don't you try setting Width as Width* on every DataGridColumn e.g. Width="100*"** like this?

Comment: I was thinking in the codebehind. But I can't find any way to get to the rows. Anyway, when I have multiple columns with a fixed MinWidth, leaving a dead area to the right, I get selection highlight over the whole row. Also, as long as I set MinWidth and *not* width on the columns, I can add a filler column at the end with Width="*" and it behaves as you want: I get a horizontal scrollbar when I make the window narrow enough. I even started creating the columns programmatically. I don't get it. You're not setting Width on them, right?

Comment: Yes, I am currently seeing that behavior as well, which is what I want. What I am trying to fix now is seeing this: http://imgur.com/EtTmBbH, on a load of the datagrid or when my program loses focus to another window. I would rather have either the whole row highlighted, or none of it. But yes, like you said, I am currently getting the whole row highlighted when I click on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make this work, I used Anton's suggestion:

> Also, a row in DataGrid consists of 2 parts, one of them is occupied by cells and the second one is not. You can set CellStyle also with the same SelectedBrush. In that case cells will be highlighted in the right color.

What I did was make a style for DataGridCellStyle and made a trigger for IsSelected:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Which paints the background of the cells the same color as the background of the selected row. This is in addition to having:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
       x:Key="DataGridRowStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This allows the painted color to extend across the entire row on load or when the program loses focus.

Answer (score 3):

You may clear default highlight color, so that your SelectedBrush would be used instead:

```
    <DataGrid ...>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I tried that, I set the color to orange. Now when I highlight a row it looks like this: http://imgur.com/HQH8wvj (I assigned the color of the SolidColorBrush to orange). The blue is in there because my selected brush is painting it that color. What I can't figure out is why/how the columns are treated differently than the empty space on the end in regards to the paint behavior of the row.

Comment: Seems that DataGrid uses SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey to highlight part of the row that is occupied by existing columns. I'd suggest to make HighlightBrushKey transparent instead of orange, and then change your SelectedBrush to whatever color you want.

Comment: Also, a row in DataGrid consists of 2 parts, one of them is occupied by cells and the second one is not. You can set CellStyle also with the same SelectedBrush. In that case cells will be highlighted in the right color.

Comment: After my datagrid is populated I immediately set the selected index to be 0. For some reason though, on load, I see this: http://imgur.com/EtTmBbH, where only the unused space on the end is highlighted. It seems like setting the selected index of the datagrid is only highlighting the area of the row that isn't occupied by cells?  that is my binding, why it is not highlighting the data in the row and is only focusing the unused area I don't know. This is only on a load of the datagrid, or when my program loses focus to another window. This is what I'm trying to solve

Comment: Could you please paste <DataGrid.Resources> section from my answer to your grid and show a screenshot?

Comment: Anton your solution worked for me! I appreciate it, what I did was set the cell style like you said to be the same as the selected brush. Now the highlight is consistent across the entire row. Thanks again, I'll mark this as answered

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution, that's actually a bit simpler:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <!-- Select everything with orange... -->
    <SolidColorBrush 
        Color="#ff9933" 
        x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
    <!-- ...all the time -->
    <SolidColorBrush 
        Color="#ff9933" 
        x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

The problem was that the entire row *was* highlighted, but when focus was lost, the "unselected" cells were highlighted with *a different color*: The Inactive Selection Highlight color.

The dead area background at the end of the row is being set by your `IsSelected=True` trigger. Get rid of that, and the dead area won't "select" at all. Use three distinct colors for that, `HighlightBrushKey`, and `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`, and it all becomes clear.

Anton Danylov was very, very close. But the answer is not to make those brushes transparent, it's to make them the color you want them to be.